# Representation of Mathematical formula

Tags: java, android, math

I would just like to check that this formula is represented the same I have wrote in my Android app. 
Right now the values I'm returning back are unexpected (from my formula in Android Studio) so i assume there is something wrong in my code. Most likely because of the n variable, as I am not sure what value n should be assigned. Any help would be really appreciated

formula A is completed, the result P0, is the "repayments" variable in B

```
//method for at end of year total
public void totalAtEndOfYear(double loan, double repayments, double interest, int years, int frequency) {

        double inside = (1 + interest / 365);
        //repayments is the result from A
        double middle = (Math.pow(inside, 365 * n) - repayments);
        double numerator = (Math.pow(inside, 365 * n) -1);
        double denominator = (Math.pow(inside, frequency) -1);
        double last = numerator / denominator;
        double total =  loan * middle * last;
}
```

Here is the formula I am suppose to be following: [image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some mapping between the formula and your code. It can be deciphered, but for example you call it formula A, but I can only see `P_0=`. Also, what you mean by middle and last should be specified.

Comment: I agree with Matthieu. And `n` is the number of the year, where `B_n` is the balance at the end of that year. k should be the days between two repayments, 7 for weekly, 30 for monthly etc.

Comment: Can you test the result of P_0 first? Maybe you also have an error there.

Comment: @GregT, thankyou for the input. I was assuming n was the year so thanks for the reassurance.

Comment: The P_0 is correct. It returns the value as expected, along with other methods that use this value. It just seems to be this method.

Comment: This method should be looped over for the number of years the total loan needs to be repayed, each year should display the remaining total for the following years to come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Matthieu mentioned, you made a mistake, but it's only partially correct. You also do addition, not just multiplication. It would look as something like this:

```
double inside = (1 + interest / 365);
//repayments is the result from A
double numerator = (Math.pow(inside, 365 * n) -1);
double denominator = (Math.pow(inside, frequency) -1);

double first = loan * Math.pow(inside, 365 * n);
double last = - repayments * numerator / denominator;

double total =  first + last;
```

Comment: Thankyou so much GregT. As I expected "n" was the number of years thankfully. I just added your version of the formula and now everything is working as expected. You have saved me many more wasted hours thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a math error.

Your middle shouldn't be substracted by repayment. It should be more like

```
middle = (Math.pow(inside, 365 * n));
(loan * middle) - (repayement * last);
```

Because in your formula they aren't parathesis. So the multiplication has the priority.

Cordially,
Matthieu

Comment: thankyou, I will fix up those two lines so that they are correct. Now that I know the formula is correct, the value of n must be incorrect because I am still not returning my correct data. By any chance would you know what "n" within the equation (e.g. power of 365*n), should that value be?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about it :/ I remember seing such a formula a couple years ago at school but I don't remember how it works

Comment: The formula is NOT correct as of now. In the formula you need to sum two different expressions, not just multiply them.

Comment: @MatthieuMeunier you're missing a paranthesis, but I cannot edit it.

Comment: There shouldn't need paranthesis, should it? The pripority of operation will multiply loan by middle and repayement by last. And substract `loan * m by r * last`

Comment: @Matthieu Right. I meant int the first row on your code, you have 2 opening parantheses, but only 1 closing. This will give a compilation error. You may remove the first one, as it's unnecessary.

Comment: Oh yeah right didn't see that one :D rough day I guess thx :)